# I am able to create a .csv file using Talend job and I want to convert .csv to .parquet file using tSystem component?

Tags: talend

I have a Talend job to create a .csv file and now I want to convert .parquet format using Talend v6.5.1. Only option I can think, tSystem component to call the python script from local or directory where .csv landing temporarily. I know I can convert this easily using pandas or pyspark but I am not sure the same code will be work for tSystem in Talend. Can you please provide the suggestions or instructions-

Code:

```
   import pandas as pd
   DF = pd.read_csv("Path")
   DF1 = to_parquet(DF)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external script on your file system, you can try

```
"python \"myscript.py\" "
```

Here is a link on talend forum regarding this problem : 
https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/how-to-execute-a-python-script-file-with-an-argument-using/m-p/23975#M3722

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the problem following below steps-

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    import pyarrow as pa
    
    import numpy as np
    
    import sys
    
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    
    test = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\your desktop\\Downloads\\TestXML\\"+ filename+".csv")
    test.to_parquet(r"C:\\Users\\your desktop\\Downloads\\TestXML\\"+ filename+".parque

t")
```